# Making ES ForEachWriter sink idempotent with structured streaming in spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming, elasticsearch-spark

I am experiencing the same situation as described in [Spark structured steaming from kafka - last message processed again after resume from checkpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41300223/spark-structured-steaming-from-kafka-last-message-processed-again-after-resume?rq=1). When I restart my spark job after a failure the last message gets processed again. One of the answers suggest that the sink has to be idempotent. I am not sure I understand this well.

Right now I write to ES sink and the 3 methods are implemented as follows:

1. open method returns true
2. process method does Http post to ES
3. close method closes the connection

I would like to know how to make the ES sink idempotent and also how to use the 2 parameters partitionId and version in the open method to return false if the data has already been processed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer in the link that you have shared ?

Comment: I think the answer was updated a couple of hours after I posted the question.Seems to work with Spark version 2.2.0

Comment: I however think you still have to answer the question how to make _"process method does Http post to ES"_ idempotent.